# Import and export without changing number format

Tags: import, data-structures

I have a complex file that is the output of a program. The file contains multiple columns with data in different number formats. For example:

```
2.026851847767830D-01
8.468918E-01
```

I want to import the data using `Import[]`. The problem is that Mathematica "reads" the numbers and converts them into objects with `Real[]` header. As I want to change only a column and the export the file into the same format, I want to be able to access the columns and leave the format unchanged, then update the desired column and export a file into the same format.

I think if there is a form to tell Mathematica that the numbers should be read as `Strings` will solve the problem.

Some ideas?

Comment: you can always `Import[file,"Text"]` , then do what you want with string operations.

Comment: No, because i want the structure to be preserved. For example, I want that a table of 3 numbers imported as {"1","2","3"} instead of {"1  2  3"}.

Comment: One you have "1 2 3" use `StringSplit` to get `{"1","2","3"}`. Your import might look  something like this: `StringSplit /@ StringSplit[ Import[file, "Text"] , "\n"]`

Comment: Yup, that's perfect!

Post that as an answer and i can set this question as answered. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example file:

```
 FilePrint["test.dat"]
```

[image]

Import as all strings breaking each line into lists, assuming space delimited:

```
 stringform = 
       StringSplit /@ StringSplit[ Import["test.dat", "Text"] , "\n"];
```

Here is an example operating on the second column of the result and writing it back out:

```
 Export["out.dat", StringJoin@Riffle[ 
       (StringJoin@Riffle[#, " "]) & /@ 
          MapAt[ToString[ToExpression[#]/2] &, stringform, {All, 2}] , 
               "\n"], "Text"];
 FilePrint["out.dat"]
```

[image]

note the columns that we didn't mess with are exactly the same.